# jQuery Cookies w/ Multiple SlideToggle Menus

Tags: jquery, cookies, slidetoggle

I have multiple menus that are using .slideToggle (im learning jQuery currently). Using online tutorials and carious other resources, I *think* that what I have should be working to remember the state of my slideToggle menus regardless of where they are on the site. There are four menus so far, this could change randomly as I make changes to the site. Here is the structure of the menus:

```
<aside class="widget">
<h2 class="trigger">Blog Topics</h2>
<ul id="menu-blog-topics" class="menu">
<li></li>
</ul>
</aside>

<aside class="widget">
<h2 class="trigger">Wordpress</h2>
<ul id="menu-wordpress-3" class="menu">
<li></li>
</ul>
</aside>
```

And my jQuery:

```
function initMenu() { 
    $('ul.menu').hide(); 
    $('h2.trigger').click( 
            function() { 
                    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow',function(){ 
                            var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
                            if ($(this).is(':hidden')) { 
                                    var state = "closed"; 
                            } else if ($(this).is(':visible')) { 
                                    var state = "open"; 
                            } 
                            return false; 
                     }); 
            } 
    ); 
} 

jQuery(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

The slideToggle functions properly. The state is just not remembered from page to page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing some lines to store and retrieve the cookie.

```
function initMenu() {   
    $('ul.menu').hide();   

    $('h2.trigger').click(   
        function() {   
            $(this).next().slideToggle('slow', function() {   
                var id = $(this).attr('id');   
                $.cookie(id, $(this).is(':hidden') ? "closed" : "open"); 
                return false;   
            });   
        }   
    ); 

    $('h2.trigger').each(function() { 
        var id = $(this).next().attr('id'); 
        if ($.cookie(id) == "open")  $(this).next().show(); 
    }); 
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

You can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/GZmHY/9/

Comment: Thanks a ton. It doesn't keep state from page to page. Is it because pages links are to a different folder? it is active on my site here: http://ajtroxell.com/

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention that you need jquery.cookie.js. You can get it here -> https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js

Comment: In your site you use another library for managing cookies. Adjust the cookie setting/getting code accordingly or use the same library I used instead.

Comment: After more trouble shooting, for some reason it is keeping the state of the initial menu state change, but if you click two or three menus it only saves the state of the first clicked and none there after. And if you change the state on the first menu (again), then it does not revert to that state on load.

Comment: Try changing `$.cookie(id, state)` to `$.cookie(id, state, {path: '/'})` and tell me what happens.